# Eyefinity 4 Monitor Setup with HDMI and DVI

Tags: multiple-monitors, eyefinity

I'm trying to setup a multi-monitor configuration.

- My graphics card has 4 display ports and 2 DVI inputs
- My monitors are 3 Full-HD TV Screens and one 22'' Monitor

I tried to setup Eyefinity: 3 Full-HD as 1 huge display + the 22" screen as primary-screen.
That means the "huge display" extends the primary screen.

I connected the 3 TVs HDMI » DP » PC. But it turns out that I have to connect them with an active adapter x » X_TO_DP(active) » PC.

I looked up and found a lot of products where x is DVI, which would work with my 22".
But the TVs only have HDMI and VGA.

Can I use one of these adapters to get my 4 monitor setup working?

- [Club 3D CAC-1002](http://www.alternate.co.uk/Club_3D/Club_3D+CAC-1002/html/product/1058938/?)
- [Club 3D DisplayPort to HDMI Adapter Cable](http://www.alternate.co.uk/Club_3D/Club_3D+DisplayPort_to_HDMI_Adapter_Cable/html/product/252066/?)

Comment: You can easily use DVI to HDMI converters I don't see the problem.

Comment: yes.. DVI will work for one screen
but what about the 3 tvs?

Comment: Again a hdmi to dvi works I need an English site with those products

Comment: The problem is, that you need a displayport for eyefinity if you have more than 2 screens

Comment: So you have you answer...